# Generate daily revenue based on a table

Tags: r

I have following table like this.

```
  Invoice Date    Payable Amount 
 -------------------------------- 
  14 Sep 2015     114            
  23 Dec 2015     5153           
  28 Dec 2015     1145           
  28 Dec 2015     5500           
  28 Dec 2015     4500           
  29 Dec 2015     8359           
  30 Dec 2015     5954           
  30 Dec 2015     3017           
  30 Dec 2015     4660           
  31 Dec 2015     10500          
  31 Dec 2015     10500
```

So I used below code to re-format it,

Below code I converted my text column to date column using strptime.

```
 data$`Invoice Date` = as.POSIXct(strptime(data$`Invoice Date`,format = "%d %b %Y"))
```

But I need to aggregate the sum(payable amount) based on date only. i.e I have 3 amount on single date(in this case 28 dec has 3 payable amount) I need to sum all three as one.

So I tried with below code,

```
data %>% group_by(`Invoice Date`=cut(`Invoice Date`,breaks = "day")) %>%
summarize(`Payable Amount` = sum(`Payable Amount`))
```

Which is not working, can anyone help.

The output I need is sum(amount) on 1 date only.

Thanks

Comment: Following works, data %>% group_by(`Invoice Date`) %>%
  summarize(`Payable Amount` = sum(`Payable Amount`))

Comment: be careful while handling date filelds

Comment: Sure...Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Following code works,

```
data %>% group_by(`Invoice Date`) %>%
summarize(`Payable Amount` = sum(`Payable Amount`))
```